# Unable to pull from git on a Ubuntu Server inside of Virtualbox

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have a Virtualbox VM with Ubuntu server running with networking set to bridged.

I've installed git, initialized a repo, added my key to my github account, and ran `ssh -T git@github.com` all with no errors.

My problem comes when I try to actually pull a repo. No matter what repo I attempt to pull, I get the error `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

So, any tips on getting this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a workaround 'fix':

The problem seems to be trying to pull in 'Bridged' mode in Virtualbox. If I switch networking to NAT I can successfully pull, then I switch back to Bridged to work locally, then back to NAT when it's time to push.

It's not the most convenient fix, but it works for now. If anyone has a suggestion to make this better, I'm all ears.

Comment: This was backwards for me.  I was using NAT, and switched to bridged to make things work.  Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Did you place your ssh keys at the default location on your VM?

> **Permission denied (publickey)**
>
> This is usually caused when ssh cannot find your keys. Make sure your
>   key is in the default location, ~/.ssh. [..]

Quote from: http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Comment: You said, you getting this error on pull a repro. Did you clone the repro first?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to set my github user and password to the command line that asks to clone the repository. Since in your vm you are not logged in github..

What I did was:
**git clone https://username:password@github.com/repositoriUrl.git**

(Being username your github user account name, password your github pass and repositoryUrl.git the url for your repository).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on NAT and also Bridge network mode. By changing the DNS addresses it seems the problem fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was leaving the first interface as bridged and adding a second interface set to NAT and now it works :)