# Git/GitHub connection issue on VM/VirtualBox

Tags: git, github, connection, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I cannot connect my Git repository on GitHub from my VM (VirtualBox / Debian):

```
# git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git .
Cloning into ....
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Then I added an entry for GitHub to my `/etc/hosts` (it will be the wrong way -- don't believe, that it is always necessary):

```
207.97.227.239  github.com
```

Now I'm getting another error:

```
# git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git .
Cloning into ....
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

We would be very grateful for your your help!

Comment: Make sure you actually do have access to github.com and/or internet.

Comment: Exactly, I have no Internet connection on my guest. Oooh... shit!.. Thanky you for the hint!

Comment: After restarting the VM everything is working! :) Thank you again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to pull from git on a Ubuntu Server inside of Virtualbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455742/unable-to-pull-from-git-on-a-ubuntu-server-inside-of-virtualbox)

Answer (score -2):

looks like you dont have any internet access...