# Ubuntu in Virtualbox cannot connect to github, port closed?

Tags: ubuntu, github, port, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 host machine in my office and I run Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtualbox. 
When I try `ssh -T  git@ssh.github.com` I get `ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Connection timed out`. However the network administrator says that port 22 and 443 are opened.
I we open all the ports, it works, but this is not a solution in the long term.

Basically what I need to know is how can I identify what port is github using.
My Network settings in virtualbox are
attached to: NAT
Adapter Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop
cable connected, enabled
Port Forwarding (no rules)

I tried Bridget adapter option to, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Do you have internet access in the VM? If not, this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117564/git-github-connection-issue-on-vm-virtualbox

Comment: Yes, I do have internet access and I can clone github repos with the http protocol. But not with git protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, it sounds like a [firewall is blocking the git protocol](https://thomashunter.name/blog/github-connection-timed-out/) — you may be able to solve the issue by ensuring that **port 9418** is also open.

The suggested solution from the linked article is to use HTTP or SSH instead; [a recent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248848/399367) notes that SSH and GIT are now very similar in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks. The port 9418 is also opened but that didn't help. I cannot use http as I'm using bitbake recipes and I would have to edit all of them to change it. I agree that it's a firewall problem. I just cannot agree with IT what port is git using, they keep saying that all the mentioned ports are always opened.

Comment: Can you telnet to that port from Windows? `telnet github.com 9418` (you may need to [install the telnet client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=WS.10).aspx) if you haven't already). If not, that's a pretty solid test case to go to your IT department with. If so, what about from the VM? I guess there's a chance VirtualBox or Windows themselves are firewalling it.

Comment: You are right. That command works for the machine that can clone git repos and it doesn't work for the one that cannot. Thanks for your help!